# Number of primes skipped by binomial coefficients?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, binomial-coefficients

Take $$B(l,n)=\binom{n+l}{n}$$ and $\mathcal P(t)=\{p\mbox{ prime}:p|t\}$.

1. What is the cardinality of $\mathcal P(B(l,n))$?
2. What is minimum cardinality of $L\subseteq\{1,\dots,n\}$ such that $$\mathcal P(\prod_{l\in L}B(l,n))\supseteq\{p\mbox{ prime}:p\leq n\}?$$
3. Take a prime $q\leq n$ and at how many $l\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ does $q|B(l,n)$?

Comment: For 2, such an $L$ most likely does not exist at all, as the left-hand side includes all primes in the interval $(n,n+\max L]$.

Comment: corrected........

Comment: What have you tried?  Did you calculate these for the first several values of n and look at the apparent growth rate?  Did you try any heuristics based on the growth of primes?  Did the results match?

Comment: If $ n = c p^r$ with $c < p/2$ then no such $L$ exists.

Comment: @WillSawin I checked $n=cp$ where $p$ is prime and $c<p/2$. The number $p$ is skipped why?

Comment: @WillSawin Is that the only oddity?

Comment: For 3, if the base $q$ representation of $n$ is $(d_1,d_2,...,d_k)$ and $d_1\geq q/2$, then the answer is $n - (q-d_1)(q-d_2)...(q-d_k)$.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev Seems a complement to Will Sawin's answer. Is there a simple reasoning?

Comment: @Turbo: Yes - [Lucas' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem).

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev $q$ needs to be prime in your statement?

Comment: @Turbo: Yes, but you said it's prime,

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev I was just wondering about composites.